# An virtualhost for many subdomains to host a global webmail

Tags: php, apache, subdomain, webmail

My server has many domains and I need that each one of them points to the same folder through a subdomain for each one of them, following the pattern: webmail.domain1.com, webmail.domain2.com, etc. I thought that it could be done with only one virtual host but its not working.

I tried with an ServerAlias with no success - maybe plesk is causing compatibility problems. Anyway this is my current virtualhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName webmail.mydefaultdomain.com.br
    ServerAlias webmail.*.com.br
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/mydefaultdomain/httpdocs/webmail"
    <Directory "/var/www/vhost/mydefaultdomain/httpdocs/webmail">
            DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride none
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Even more, some subdomains like that already exists pointing to another webmail, I need a way to override that configuration with this new one.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow Jean Carlo. I think your question is better suited in [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com). Besides: I never saw wildcards in the middle of a server name (which does not mean I does not work and the the Apache docs neither allow nor disallow them, but you might check this first ;).

Comment: I have no practical experience of wildcard sub-domains, but is seems like a dns issue, as well as apache. Internet search: 'apache wildcard subdomain' is 'interesting'. The first one i checked may be useful: [Articles/apache wildcard domain]